# Fixed table header WITH dynamic width table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I've found countless Fixed Header table examples online and as many StackOverflow posts on the subject, but have yet to find one that allows for a dynamic width table that resizes with the browser. Anytime I try to make the width dynamic the thead columns won't align with the tbody columns. Here's a fraction of the samples I've tried:

- [Pure CSS version 1](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html)
- [Pure CSS version 2](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html)
- [FixedTableHeader](http://fixedheadertable.com/) (which I can't get to work with jQuery 1.9.1)
- [FloatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/)

jqGrid and Data Tables seem to work, but I'm trying to build a table using Knockout and would prefer to avoid both - we're actually moving away from jqGrid entirely.

Anyone suggestions?

**UPDATE -** 
I stand (or sit) corrected. [jQuery.floatThead does support dynamic width tables](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/DxX2T/2/), and the header columns line up with the body columns on window resize. I guess 50th time's a charm? I just hid the horizontal scrollbar with `overflow-x:hidden;` and wrapped the table in a div, which is supported by the plugin:

```
var $table = $('.myTable');
$table.floatThead({
    scrollContainer: function ($table) {
        return $table.closest('.wrapper');
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a complex situation in which I allow for my header to be its own object that stretches with the browser. I then handle $(window).resize and simply match up the widths of columns in my data table to be the width of their corresponding header columns.

Comment: @beau - I was thinking that might be my only (best?) solution, but of course, right after posting this question I may have this working using the jQuery.floatThead plugin. I'll update my post if that's the case

Comment: I'm still annoyed that having a thead and tbody alone doesn't allow this by default. If you think about it, whatever 'plugin' you use is probably doing the same thing, but for more generic cases...spinning your own up for your situation(s) would probably be much less overhead.

Comment: @beau - check out the rendered HTML in that fiddle I added in the update. It's an interesting approach.

Comment: Yeah...it's a start. The 2 things I notice is the lack of a fixed footer and the fact the scrollbar doesn't limit itself to the height/position of the tbody. I've searched the same lengths you probably have and chose to roll one...maybe we should make another plugin...ha.

Comment: It was so close! In that fiddle if you maximize the window (Chrome, FF), then shrink it by clicking the browser's maximize button again, not by click + dragging, the table doesn't resize correctly.

Comment: I think I fixed that resizing issue you speak of in the latest version. (maybe, or maybe its that windows bug I cant fix on my mac)

Comment: You should put your update in an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary solution was to resize the table multiple times on window resize

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    ResizeFloatThead();
});
ResizeFloatThead = function () {

    var interval = 500;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.myTable').floatThead('reflow');
        }, interval);
        interval -= 100;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This I believe is a quite simple solution to your problem. It involves jquery. As I am quite new to this site, I may have misunderstood, but here goes. Basically upon page load or resize, the jquery script checks for each of the columns which is widest of head and body and then adjusts the narrower one to the wider one. The columns of both header and body adjust upon window resize (with the occasional lag). The enclosing `<div>` makes it work better for reasons unknown to me. If I am barking up the wrong tree, please let me know. Note that the php bit is just my lazy way of creating lots of rows and columns – not at all vital to the solution which is in the script section.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
p,th,td {
font-family:Arial;
}

td {
padding:10px;
}
tr#head {
    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    font-weight:bold;
}

</style>

<body>

<?php //make large table using php
$cols = 7; //how many columns
echo "
<div class='wrapper'>
<table class='tab'>
<tbody id='head'>
<tr id='head'>";
for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){
  echo "<td>heading {$i}</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody><tbody id='body'>";
for($h=0;$h<=100;$h++){
  echo "<tr>";
  for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){
    echo "
    <td>row {$h} column no. {$i}</td>";
   }
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>

jQuery(function($) {

$(window).resize(function() {
  tabcols();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  tabcols();
});
});

function tabcols(){
 var cols = 7;
 var h = $("tr#head").height();
 $("tbody#body").find("tr:eq(0)").find("td").css("padding-top",h); //add extra space to keep the fixed header from obscuring top of body
 for(i=0;i<cols;i++){ //check each column for td width
   var tdsel = "td:eq(" + i + ")";
   var bodyw = $("tbody#body").find(tdsel).width();
   var headw = $("tbody#head").find(tdsel).width();
   if(bodyw > headw){
      $("tbody#head").find(tdsel).width(bodyw);
   } else {
      $("tbody#body").find(tdsel).width(headw);
   }
 }
};

</script>

</body></html>
```